# Extract multiple .tar.gz files with a single tar call

Tags: tar

I was wondering whether (and, of course, how) it’s possible to tell `tar` to extract multiple files in a single run.

I’m an experienced Unix user for several years and of course I know that you can use `for` or `find` or things like that to call `tar` once for each archive you want to extract, but I couldn’t come up with a working command line that caused my `tar` to extract two .tar.gz files at once. (And no, there’s nothing wrong with `for`, I’m merely asking whether it’s possible to do without.)

I’m asking this question rather out of curiosity, maybe

- there’s a strange fork of `tar` somewhere that supports this
- someone knows how to use the `-M` parameter that `tar` suggested to me when I tried `tar -zxv -f a.tgz -f b.tgz`
- we’re all blind and it’s totally easy to do — but I couldn’t find any hint in the web that didn’t utilize `for` or `find` or `xargs` or the like.

Please don’t reply with `tar -zxvf *.tar.gz` (because that does **not** work) and only reply with “doesn’t work” if you’re absolutely sure about it (and maybe have a good explanation *why*, too).

**Edit:** I was pointed to [an answer to this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583889/how-can-you-untar-more-than-one-file-at-a-time/583891#583891) which says in great detail that it’s not possible without breaking current `tar` syntax, but I don’t think that’s true. Using `tar -zxv -f a.tgz -f b.tgz` or `tar -zxv --all-args-are-archives *.tar.gz` would break no existing syntax, imho.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the situation that caused you to start thinking about how to avoid a looping construct?

Comment: FYI: GNU tar supports [multi-volume tar archives](http://paulbradley.tv/44/) with the `-M` parameter.

Comment: unclejamil: I’m writing a HowTo and one of the steps in it involves unpacking several compressed files (.tar.bz2, .tar.gz, .zip). And since it’s a HowTo, I was wondering what the most elegant command line to do that would be. :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is possible, the syntax is pretty easy:

```
$ cat *.tar | tar -xvf - -i
```

The -i option ignores the EOF at the end of the tar archives, from the man page:

```
-i, --ignore-zeros
ignore blocks of zeros in archive (normally mean EOF)
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me. Exact command I used was: `cat *.tar.bz2 | tar -ixjv`. Thanks!

Comment: <For tgz> cat *.tgz | tar -xzvf - -i -C /destination/ <or>
for file in *.tgz; do tar -xzvf $file -C /destination/; done

Comment: @polynomial: is there any reason, why we cant use ls instead of cat? wouldnt that work as well?

Comment: @Rika, `tar -f -` reads from `stdin`, hence one needs to pipe the content of the archives, not their names. That's why `ls` wouldn't work.

Comment: @DanielLe Thanks a lot really appreciate it

Comment: to call this syntax easy is a stretch. `tar -xf *.tar` would be easy (and intuitive)

Comment: This doesn't work on latest ubuntu:
tar (child): -i: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @HamsterWithPitchfork: Sounds to me like you’ve typed `tar -xvf -i` instead of `tar -xvf - -i`. That’s because `-f` requires a filename to follow. The special filename `-` means “standard input”, i.e. whatever is being piped into tar. If you omit that dash, tar will instead interpret the following `-i` as the file name. That file doesn’t exist, which is why it’s telling you `-i: Cannot open: No such file or directory`.

Comment: And, by the way, `-f -` can probably be omitted altogether, because without `-f`, tar will read from standard input (or write to standard output, depending on the operation) anyway. So instead of `tar -xvf - -i` you could also write `tar -xvif -` and even `tar -xvi`.

Answer (score 42):

For ***.tar.gz**:

```bsh
for file in *.tar.gz; do tar -zxf "$file"; done
```

For ***.tar.bz2**:

```bsh
for file in *.tar.bz2; do tar -jxf "$file"; done
```

For ***.tar.xz**:

```bsh
for file in *.tar.xz; do tar -Jxf "$file"; done
```

For ***.tar.zst** <sup>new</sup>:

```bsh
for file in *.tar.zst; do tar --zstf -xf "$file"; done
```

Comment: this is great. the format is also great because thats how it looks in the terminal

Comment: Don't forget to put quotes around `$file` if your files have names with spaces.

Comment: This does not really answer the question of whether it's possible to extract multiple archives using a single invocation of tar. Furthermore, the user says they are already familiar with how to use for-loops to iterate over a set of files.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a loop. It wouldn't break the `tar` command line syntax to allow multiple `-f` options, but it would require adding code to process several archives in sequence, with all kinds of edge conditions (What happens if an archive in the middle is malformed? Can the archives use different compression mechanisms? Can you have multiple `-C` options (GNU tar option to extract to a particular directory), too? What about -K (GNU tar option to start at a certain member name)? …).

One possibility avoiding a `for` loop is to install and activate [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/), a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem that provides transparent access to archives. Each archive `/path/to/archive` doubles as a directory `~/.avfs/path/to/archive#`. If you want to match the archives with wildcards, there's a hurdle of adding that `#` to a wildcard match; it can be done in zsh.

```
mountavfs
cp -p ~/.avfs$PWD/{a,b}.tgz\#/* /destination
cp -p ~/.avfs/path/to/source/*.tgz(e\''REPLY=$REPLY\#'\')/* /destination
```